# Nested custom ContentControl not being displayed

Tags: c#, wpf, contentcontrol

I've got nested custom ContentControls, and I'm having difficulty getting the inner control to render inside of the outer control.  Here's an example of how the two controls are composed:

```
<Window ...>
    <StackPanel>
        <local:Outer> <!-- Nothing in here gets displayed -->
            <local:Inner>
                <TextBlock>Fahrvergnügen</TextBlock>
            </local:Inner>
        </local:Outer>
        <local:Inner> <!-- This is displayed just fine -->
            <TextBlock>some text</TextBlock>
        </local:Inner>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Inner and Outer's styles are defined as follows:

```
<ResourceDictionary ...>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:Outer}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:Outer}">
                    <ContentPresenter />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:Inner}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:Inner}">
                    <ContentPresenter />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

An added wrinkle is that Outer is using a ContentPropertyAttribute that points to a List:

```
[ContentPropertyAttribute("InnerItems")]
public class Outer : ContentControl
{
    private List<Inner> innerItems = new List<Inner>();

    static Outer()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(Outer), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(Outer)));
    }

    public List<Inner> InnerItems { get { return this.innerItems; } }
}
```

For completeness, here's Inner's definition, which is trivial:

```
public class Inner : ContentControl
{
    static Inner()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(Inner), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(Inner)));
    }
}
```

I'm guessing the problem is that Outer's content cannot be displayed with a simple `<ContentPresenter />` but I'm not sure what to replace it with.  Suggestions?